# Find all possible combinations of a column in a dataframe when fixing a value in another column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a Graph network of authors and movies. Authors that participated in at least one movie should be connected. I already created my vertice dataframe containing the author's information. I am having trouble to create an edges dataframe that show this connection. I have the following dataframe:

```
author_ID | movie_ID
nm0000198 | tt0091954
nm0000198 | tt0468569
nm0000198 | tt4555426
nm0000354 | tt0134119
nm0000354 | tt0091954
nm0000721 | tt0091954
```

I would like to somehow fix the movie and create all possible combinations of authors that participated in that movie. Like:

```
movie_ID | author_A   | author_B
tt0091954| nm0000198  | nm0000354
tt0091954| nm0000198  | nm0000721
tt0091954| nm0000354  | nm0000721
```

Please help if you can. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a self join

```py
dfA = df.withColumnRenamed('author_ID', 'author_A')
dfB = df.withColumnRenamed('author_ID', 'author_B')
dfA \
    .join(dfB, on=(dfA.movie_ID == dfB.movie_ID) & (dfA.author_A < dfB.author_B)) \
    .drop(dfB.movie_ID) \
    .show()

        +---------+---------+---------+
        | author_A| author_B| movie_ID|
        +---------+---------+---------+
        |nm0000198|nm0000354|tt0091954|
        |nm0000198|nm0000721|tt0091954|
        |nm0000354|nm0000721|tt0091954|
        +---------+---------+---------+
```

The `<` clause is to make sure we only get the tuple `(author_A, author_B)` once

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Just another way to write self-join.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

joining_condition = [col("a.movie_ID") == col("b.movie_ID") , col("a.author_ID") > col("b.author_ID") ]

df.alias("a")\
    .join(df.alias("b"), joining_condition)\
    .selectExpr("a.movie_ID AS movie_Id",
                "a.author_ID AS author_A",
                "B.author_ID AS author_B")\
    .show()

#+---------+---------+---------+
#| movie_Id| author_A| author_B|
#+---------+---------+---------+
#|tt0091954|nm0000354|nm0000198|
#|tt0091954|nm0000721|nm0000198|
#|tt0091954|nm0000721|nm0000354|
#+---------+---------+---------+
```